# Rider: Unable to resolve assemblies for Solution

Tags: rider

I use rider extensively for work. Lately I have noticed that it is unable to resolve assemblies and nugets in my Solution. My current project has lots of project. The solution works fine in Visual Studio but not in Rider. In some of the files it is even unable to resolve primitive types.

```
Cannot resolve symbol int
2 Cannot resolve symbol ‘Gui
© Cannot resolve symbol ‘string’
© Cannot resolve symbol ‘int'

© Cannot resolve symbol ‘int’

© Cannot resolve symbol ‘bool’
© Cannot resolve symbol ‘string’
© Cannot resolve symbol ‘bool’
0 The type System. Guid is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly ‘mscoriib, Version 0, Culture=neutral, PubliceyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

© The type 'System.DateTime' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly ‘mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PubliceyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
© Cannot resolve symbol ‘DateTime"
© The type 'System.DateTime' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly ‘mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5¢561934089".
```

My Rider info

```
JetBrains Rider 2022.3.1

Build #RD-223.8214.53, built on December 20, 2022

Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.23 amd64

VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Windows 11 10.0

.NET 7.0.0 (Server GC)

GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation

Memory: 1500M

Cores: 16

Registry:

    ide.experimental.ui=true

    vcs.empty.toolwindow.show=false

    platform.projectModel.workspace.model.file.index=false

    ide.new.project.model.index.case.sensitivity=true

    rdclient.asyncActions=false

    indexing.enable.entity.provider.based.indexing=false

    ide.workspace.model.rbs.as.tree=false

    database.show.search.tab=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:

    com.intellij.resharper.HeapAllocationsViewer (2022.3.1)

    ru.adelf.idea.dotenv (2022.3)
```

More information here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-69583/Rider-issues-with-nuget-packages

I have tried cleaning the cache and restarting the IDE but it was of no use.

Comment: My guess is that you should do as the error messages say and **add a reference to assembly ‘mscoriib, Version 0, Culture=neutral, PubliceyToken=b77a5c561934e089"**. You've either got a reference missing completely, or you're referencing the wrong version.